# The Tridion Linking service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s)

Tags: 2011-sp1, dynamic-linking

One of the client had CPU 100% on one of the w3wp production deployer process running Tridion 2011 SP1 and the website was not responding. We had to restart to fix the issue.

1) we noticed there was no heavy publishing during that time.
2) error on event log shows The Tridion Linking service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s)
3) no Error on deployer log or core logs

please let me know if any one faced similar

Comment: I am very rusty on 2011... but do you actually _need_ the Linking Service? IIRC, this was there to provide support for COM based websites. Are you running a Classic ASP site?

Comment: Yes  80% of the website is still running on vb script templating  and asp.